# smooth rounded corners in swift

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners

How can I create a UIButton with rounded corners that are smooth? 
The standard apple rounded corners are much nicer than the standard rounded corners. 
If I design a button in sketch, I can toggle "smooth corners" which toggles the corners of a shape from Apple rounded corners (smooth) to standard rounded corners.

Here is a comparison:

[image]

How can I toggle this in swift?

`showContentButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20` rounds the corners, however, I don't really know if this rounded corners are "smooth corners" or "standard rounded corners". And I don't know how to toggle this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Starting **iOS 13.0**, you can just use this property in addition to setting the cornerRadius:

```
sampleButton.layer.cornerCurve = .continuous
```

This is also easily animatable, which previously resulted in problems using a UIBezierPath.

See more at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/3152596-cornercurve

Answer (score 29):

**Prior to iOS 13**

To get that effect you can use `UIBezierPath`

[image: Smooth corners]

**Edit:**
Usage in UIView

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let myButton UIButton = UIButton()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // your roundPath code here
    }

}
```

**Edit 2:**

Use this approach for rounding specific corners:

```
let roundPath = UIBezierPath(
    roundedRect: bounds,
    byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight],
    cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
)
```

[Source](https://twitter.com/nathangitter/status/992842150500069376)

Comment: the button disappeared completely. I did: `let smoothCornersRoundedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 8)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = smoothCornersRoundedPath.cgPath
        showContentButton.layer.mask = maskLayer`

Comment: did you do that in `layoutSubviews` method?

Comment: my button is inside a UIView class.

Comment: The button has only one rounded corner. But it seems like it is a smooth corner. But all other three corners are sharp (90°)

Comment: It just doesn't fit the rect of your view. Try adding some constraints first or however you do the layout.

Comment: it no works: `let smoothCornersRoundedPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: showContentButton.bounds, cornerRadius: 8)`. I had to add `showContenButton.bounds` instead of just `bounds`.

Comment: Well of course. You apply corner radius to your button and not to the superview.

Comment: one last question: How can I restrict the corner radius to specific corners? For instance: the top right and bottom right corner should be rounded, but the top left and bottom left corners should be sharp.

Comment: @WalterBeiter I know it's been a while but can you please accept the answer? :)

Comment: this answer works and solved my question, however the answer from @Vincent Friedrich is definitely better if you are on iOS 13 or above

Comment: @WalterBeiter thanks! I've aded memo that my solution goes prior to iOS 13.

Answer (score 3):

Just use this extension

```
extension CALayer {

   func roundCorners(radius: CGFloat) {
       let roundPath = UIBezierPath(
           roundedRect: self.bounds,
           cornerRadius: radius)
       let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
       maskLayer.path = roundPath.cgPath
       self.mask = maskLayer
   }

}
```

and use it like this

```
cell.layer.roundCorners(radius: 18)
```

Comment: you can't add a CALayer like that.  when you add a CALayer, you need to update the frame in `layoutSubviews` every time `layoutSubviews` is called (this is the whole purpose of layoutSubviews)

Answer (score 3):

For SwiftUI, you can try this:

```
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous))
```

Example:

```
Rectangle()
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 24, style: .continuous))
    .padding()
```

or use extension:

```
extension View {
    func smoothCornerRadius(_ x: CGFloat) -> some View {
        return self
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: x, style: .continuous))
    }
}
```

[Result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYxzu.png)

Comment: I believe Nhat Nguyen Duc should be bountied. Because his answer is the most Swifty available here. And it's not bounded to any global property change.