# Flutter: Smooth rounded corners

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I would like to know how to make a smooth rounded corner in Flutter. I found a similar link to iOS approach - [smooth rounded corners in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310339/smooth-rounded-corners-in-swift) but it did not help me find a solution to Flutter approach. I thought [ContinuousRectangleBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ContinuousRectangleBorder-class.html) is the way, but it is not the shape I am looking for. I think some kind of clipper should work.

Comment: `Smooth rounded corner` ? You mean `rounded corner` ?

Comment: No, smooth rounded corner radius, there is link to similar issue. Here is the explanation https://medium.com/@arthurofbabylon/a-smooth-corner-radius-in-ios-54b80aa2d372

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I published a dedicated package that might help you : [figma_squircle](https://pub.dev/packages/figma_squircle).

```dart
Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.75),
        shape: SmoothRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: SmoothBorderRadius(
              cornerRadius: 10,
              cornerSmoothing: 0.5,
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try the following code

```dart
ClipRRect(
borderRadius:
      BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
child: // Your widget that needs to be rounded.
)
```

For more information, you can check [this reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI43jkQkrvs)

Comment: Clip.hardEdge does not sound like "smooth" approach

Comment: Clip.hardEdge is Optional. You can leave this line...

Comment: Try To use without clip.hardEdge

Comment: The problem is to make smooth transition between the "edges", otherwise I know to make rounder corners.

Answer (score -2):

There is no natural way to do this with Flutter. If you really want to accomplish this, use the technique used in your [article](https://medium.com/@arthurofbabylon/a-smooth-corner-radius-in-ios-54b80aa2d372) where you overlay the square with a circle with a `Stack` widget. This looks like the following:

```
Stack(children: [
          Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.amber,
              )),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.amber,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
            ),
          ),
        ]),
```

This will create a square that looks like:

[image]

You might need to mess around with the height and width of the square and the circle but you get the idea.